# Role based access control where a user can have multiple roles in multiple scenarios

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database-design

I am creating a MERN app where there are multiple users and each user has their specific roles specified. A user can also have two roles at once in two separate scenarios.

Scenario: A user can have multiple sites and a site can have multiple users. The user(user1) who has created the site(site1) will be the `Owner` and be able to perform CRUD operations on the site(site1) but when an `Owner` invites another user(user2) to the site, the new user(user2) is the `Editor` of this site(site1) and he can only Read and Update the site(site1).

Similarly, if the second user(user2) creates another site(site2), he is the `Owner` of this site(site2) and `Editor` of site1.

So basically a user will be the Owner of the site created by himself and will be the Editor of the site which has been shared with him by the owner. He is an `Owner` of his own site and `Editor` of site shared to him. I am not very sure what should be the ideal schema design for this.

The two schemas I have created so far `User` and `Site`:

**UserSchema**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    email: {type: String},
    sites: [{ site: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Site' },
              siteRole: { type: String } } 
           ]})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

**SiteSchema**

```
const SiteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name: { type: String },
     url: { type: String },
     users: [{ site: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
              siteRole: { type: String } } 
           ]})
    })
module.exports = mongoose.model('Site', SiteSchema)
```

Role 1: `Owner`: Can `Create`, `Read`, `Update`, `Delete` and `Invite an editor` a site.

Role 2: `Editor`: Can only `Read`, `Update` a site.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment you but it is neccesary to have 2 collections in your bussiness logic? If not, you could add two arrays in UserSchema defining isOwner: [/*The sites where he is owner*/] and isEditor: [/*Sites where he is editor*/]